Angular Bootstrap navbar toggle links
I've gotten deep into the weeds for deployed Angular refreshing. I think my newest issue is related. I'm using a typical bootstrap navbar toggle. In the mobile mode, if using regular html, clicking on an expanded navbar link will redirect the page. In the Angular version, clicking on a link does not "reload" the page or collapse the expanded toggler. Any tips?
I've been comparing my elements console and can't notice any difference, which makes me think the problem is related to SPA routing.

Building a well-functioning bootstrap navbar for angular is quite challenging. Have you tried using a dedicated library like this one? Here's a demo
